How to prevent GUI from stealing focus in AHK v2 (like Progress worked in v1)
I'm trying to convert some code from v1 to v2, and converting a Progress to a GUI results in GUI windows which steal focus, how do I prevent this? The GUI windows I want are just messages, there are no controls, no reason to click on them or type into them.

Got the answer from the AHK forum, it is the "NoActivate" option.
